# Ckeditor - link element navigate to relative path instead of absolute path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor

In CkEditor, I use `link` element for the text `test`.

When I click the link, it should go to `www.google.com`.

But instead it go to `http://localhost:3000/posts/www.google.com`, while
`http://localhost:3000/posts` is my current path

[image]

When I hover the link, it shows below:
[image]